# Stack overflow when overloading << operator

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class aClass
{
public:
    char *message;

    aClass(const char *message);
    ~aClass(){delete[] message;}
};

aClass::aClass(const char* newmessage)
{
    message = new char[strlen(newmessage) +1];
    strcpy(message,newmessage);
}

const ostream& operator<<(const ostream& o, const aClass &a)
{
    o << a.message;
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    aClass b("Hello");
    cout << b;
}
```

Can someone explain to me why the code above produces an infinite loop?

Comment: Why not just use `std::string`?

Comment: Note that you're breaking the [rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29). If I copy your class, boom. You need a copy-constructor and assignment operator as well, use the [copy-and-swap idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom). Note that you should really just be using `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because you have `const` where it shouldn't be:

```
/////                     /////
const ostream& operator<<(const ostream& o, const aClass &a)
```

The output stream is suppose to be non-const; after all, outputting data is changing something. So when you do this:

```
o << a.message;
```

It cannot use the normal overload for `char*`, because that one operates on a non-const stream. Instead, it searches for an appropriate overload and finds yours, determines it can construct an `aClass` from `a.message` (because your constructor is not `explicit`), does so, and calls it. This repeats forever.

It should be written as:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const aClass &a)
{
    o << a.message;
    return o;
}
```

Comment: And make the constructor `explicit` while you're at it. Or better yet, **just use `std::string`**!

Comment: Aside from this, aClass is fragile (it doesn't have private copy-constructors & assignment operatorts) and inefficient (the result of strlen should be stored to a local then memcpy should be used in place ot strcpy).